# SQL Server 2014 System out of Memory Suggestions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2014 database with two very large tables, `ARTICLES_NEW` which has 17,000,000 rows, and another table `dbo.[203]` with 705,000,000 rows.

I want to join those tables and insert the result into another table, but whenever I try to run the query, after 2 hours of executing, I get an error

> 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

or SSMS will close itself. I created all missing indexes and can't figure out how to solve this.

The other tables `dbo.[100]` and `dbo.[001]` are small tables with around 5000 rows each.

The function `dbo.CLEAN_NUMBER` just removes non-alphabetical characters.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance...

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    art.ART_ID,
    dbo.CLEAN_NUMBER(al.REFNO) AS [ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER],
    al.REFNO AS [ARL_DISPLAY_NR],
    IIF(mf.COMPARE = 1, 4, 3) AS ARL_KIND,
    al.MANNO AS [ARL_BRA_ID],
    ISNULL(sup.BRANDNAME, mf.MANCODE) AS [ARL_BRA_BRAND]
FROM
    dbo.[203] al
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ARTICLES_NEW art ON art.ART_ARTICLE_NR = al.ARTNO
                         AND CAST(art.ART_SUP_ID AS SMALLINT) = al.BRANDNO
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[100] mf ON mf.MANNO = al.MANNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.[001] sup ON sup.MANNO = mf.MANNO
WHERE 
    al.REFNO IS NOT NULL;
```

This are my table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ARTICLES_NEW]
(
    [ART_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ART_ARTICLE_NR] [nvarchar](22) NOT NULL,
    [ART_SEARCH_NR] [nvarchar](22) NOT NULL,
    [ART_SUP_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ART_SUP_BRAND] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ART_SUP_MANNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESIG_GENARTNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ARL_KIND] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ARTICLES_NEW] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ART_ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[203]
(
    [ARTNO] [VARCHAR](22) NULL,
    [BRANDNO] [SMALLINT] NULL,
    [TABLENO] [SMALLINT] NULL,
    [MANNO] [INT] NULL,
    [COUNTRYCODE] [VARCHAR](3) NULL,
    [REFNO] [VARCHAR](22) NULL,
    [EXCLUDE] [SMALLINT] NULL,
    [SORTNO] [INT] NULL,
    [ADDITIVE] [SMALLINT] NULL,
    [REFERENCEINFO] [VARCHAR](3) NULL,
    [DELETEFLAG] [SMALLINT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is code for the `clean_number` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CLEAN_NUMBER]
    (@STR VARCHAR(105))
RETURNS VARCHAR(105)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LEN INT = LEN(@STR);
    DECLARE @I INT = 1;
    DECLARE @NEWSTR VARCHAR(105) = '';
    DECLARE @C CHAR;

    WHILE (@I <= @LEN)
    BEGIN
        SET @C = SUBSTRING(@STR, @I, 1);

        IF @C >= 'a' 
           AND @C <= 'z'
           OR @C >= 'A'
              AND @C <= 'Z'
           OR @C >= '0'
              AND @C <= '9'
        BEGIN
            SET @NEWSTR = CONCAT(@NEWSTR, @C);
        END;

        SET @I = @I + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @NEWSTR;
END;
```

Also, tried this function for removing non-alphanumeric characters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaNumericCharacters] 
    (@Temp NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    RETURN @Temp
END
```

Just for reference, I run this query on a machine with 128 GB of memory

Comment: Is there error from SSMS or SQL Server? Include the *actual* error. We don't know what indexes you have or the structure of your tables so have no way to know if they are optimal. Your *scalar function* will be forcing SQL Server to go RBAR. Your *join* condition for `art` table is not sargable and will be forcing a table scan.

Comment: if possible pls add here your tables structure.

Comment: Sounds like the `System.OutOfMemoryException` is coming from SSMS, not the SQL Server process. This can happen when trying to display very large result sets in Results to Grid mode. Try running your query in SSMS from another machine that has more memory available to it (and/or increase the size of the Windows paging file(s) so that it can swap memory of other processes out to disk).

Comment: How many rows are returned by the query? SSMS is a 32-bit application so a large result set will run into memory issues. If the result set is large and you only need a sample, add a TOP clause. If you need the full result, the answer depends  on what you plan to do with it.

Comment: @DanGuzman I Don't want to display the results, I Only Want joined data to be inserted in another table, So I have insert into table from above select

Comment: You are joining an `int` with a `smallint` - columns on either side of a join should be the same data type, you should be able to alter `ART_SUP_ID` to be `smallint`

Comment: If you want to insert the results into a new table, why not just do that? Does the target table exist? If not you can `select <columns> into NewTable from...`

Comment: Your scalar functions could and should be re-written to be set-based and be used as `inline table valued functions` this will likely improve the query performance greatly.

Comment: @user3782230, the query in your question has no insert or INTO clause so all results are returned to SSMS.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to `SELECT` them rather than `INSERT` them. SSMS can't handle so many rows, not surprising it crashed. There are many performance issues with the above query also, that is probably not the direct cause of your problem but you should fix them anyway. Also why do you have `DISTINCT`? It usually indicates badly though joins, you should look at each join and consider if it is giving you duplicates and what you can do about it, rather than chucking `DISTINCT` at the query to make them go away